# Cannot resolve symbol view - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have been following this tutorial to switch activites with a button - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

I am getting the error "Cannot resolve symbol view" from searching this is usually because people haven't imported View, I have.

Also seems to think newPacket is a variable "Variable 'newPacket' is never used"

Can't for the life of me workout what is going wrong here

```
package com.alexitconsoluting.app.contactclock;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainClock extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_clock);

        public void newPacket(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewPacket.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can't create a method inside a method

Comment: You need to put your `newPacket()` outside the `onCreate()` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a method inside method which is not allowed

Create Outside of `OnCreate()`

```
public class MainClock extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_clock);


    }

        public void newPacket(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewPacket.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Comment: don't post java code with snippet formatting.

Comment: ok @VivekMishra will keep on mind thank you :)